# Is $\langle 18,81\rangle$ a subgroup of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_{135}$?

Tags: group-theory

Whilst answering my homework, I have noticed that a question has said that I need to consider the subgroups of $A=\mathbb{Z}_{135}$, including $W=\langle 18,81\rangle$. I was under the impression that for a subset to be a subgroup $a+b$ in the subgroup had to be in the subgroup as well. $18+81 = 99\mod{135}$ which isn't in the subgroup.

Is it my reasoning or the problem sheet that is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The notation $<H>$ usually refers to the subgroup generated by the set $H \subseteq G$ where $G$ is a group.

Comment: Thank you! The question makes far more sense now. I'm glad it's just notation and not all my beliefs about group theory being taken away!

Comment: The question got answered in a comment and the answer got commented in an answer... Where is the world coming to!

Answer (score 2):

*For the sake of having an answer, Adrián's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14123/is-langle-18-81-rangle-a-subgroup-of-the-abelian-group-mathbbz-135?rq=1#comment30719_14123):*

> The notation $\langle H \rangle$ usually refers to the subgroup generated by the set $H \subseteq G$ where $G$ is a group.